# Trapezoidal vs Simpsons Rule

Tags: integration

I've a question and wanna solve it using Trapezoidal or Simpsons rule. Please suggest that which method will be suitable and preferable in this case and why? After doing many examples, I'm still unable to decide anyone of these methods nor able to identify the better approach. Here's the question:

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpson's rule is exact for polynomials upto degree 3, so it is preferable compared
 to the trapezoidal rule (only exact for polynomials upto degree 1). In the concrete
 situation, you have 8 nodes, so that you cannot use simpson's rule alone.

So I would suggest to apply simpson's rule for the intervals 
 [0.8 , 1.2], [1.2 , 1.6] and [1.6 , 2.0]
 and apply the trapezoidal rule for the remaining interval 
 [0.6 , 0.8].